# How to update one field's value based on another for each item in Meteor collection? (client-side, no persistence)

Tags: meteor

Using Meteor JS, I'd like to display a list of items, price, and quantities in a table. The database contains just names and prices(per item). When a user changes the quantity field, I'd like the price to be updated. However, I don't need the quantities to be stored on the server.

Html:

```
<template name="list">
  <tbody>
    {{#each items}}
      {{> item}}
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</template>

<template name="item">
  <tr class="item {{selected}}">
    <td class="name">{{name}}</td>
    <td class="qty">
      <input class="qty" name="qty" id="qty" type="text" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td class="macro">{{calc price}}g</td>
  </tr>    
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.list.items = function () {
  return Items.find({});
};

Template.item.calc = function(price){
  var price = Number(num);
  var qty = 1;//This is where we need to retrieve the relevant quantity
  return price*qty;
}
```

I can think of three possible approaches.

1. Store the items into a client-side collection that also contains quantities. Add an event listener to the quantity input, update collection accordingly when value changes. Concern - what happens when we need to update other fields(ie name) and actually persist them?
2. Store a itemId-quantity map in Session, calculate prices in Template.list.items or in Template.item.calc
3. Store a local client-side collection with just itemId and quantity, calculate prices same as in #2

I'd like to know what the best approach would be in terms of efficiency

Comment: if you are willing to consider another library, then this could be a great usecase for ConstraintJS (http://cjs.from.so/). This is the kind of stuff it is made for, I believe.

Comment: @ChristianFritz I looked at the linked page, it seems that ConstraintJS implements sub-set of funcitonality of Meteor Blaze?

Comment: @imslavko: oh, I meant in addition to meteor, not instead of.

Comment: @ChristianFritz anyway, handlebars syntax, autoupdating properties, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another approach similar to #2 except not using `Session`. Store an itemId-quantity map as you described, but attach a reactive dependency to each item. This way, when one quantity changes, only the affected item updates.

```
var qtys = {};

Template.item.created = function () {
  qtys[this.data._id] = {
    value: 1,
    dep: new Deps.Dependency
  };
};

Template.item.destroyed = function () {
  qtys[this.data._id] = null;
}

Template.item.calc = function (price){
  var price = Number(num);
  var qty = qtys[this._id];
  qty.dep.depend();
  return price*qty.value;
}

Template.item.events({
  'change input.qty': function (ev) {
    var qty = qtys[this._id];
    qty.value = $(ev.target).val();
    qty.dep.changed();
  }
});
```

In the future, this will get even easier when helpers can access the template instance. Then you could store the value and dependency in the template instance and `qtys` would not be necessary.

From [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_created):

> In a later release, the template instance object (or something like it) will be visible from helper functions, and created will be a useful way to set up values that are read from helpers.